# Solve $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} X + \alpha^2 X = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I want to solve the following ODE:

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}X(x) + \alpha^2 X(x) = 0$$
$$ X(0) = X(L) $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx} X(0) = \frac{d}{dx}X(L) $$

So I know the general solution is given by:

$$ X(x) = c \cdot \text{cos}(\alpha x) + d \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha x) $$

But I am having trouble with the boundary conditions. The conditions imply:

1. $ c = c \cdot \text{cos}(\alpha L) + d \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha L)$
2. $ \alpha d = \alpha d \cdot \text{cos}(\alpha L) - c\alpha \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha L)$

If I add these equations, I get:

$$ c + \alpha d = (c + \alpha d) \cdot \text{cos}(\alpha L) + (d - \alpha c) \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha L) $$

Now, I can divide by $c + \alpha d$, and if force $\frac{d - \alpha c}{c + \alpha d} = 1$ I can get $1 = cos(\alpha L) + sin(\alpha L)$, whose RHS looks like this:

[image]

Which definitely has periodic solutions $\alpha_n$. But somehow this doesn't seem right to me.

---

**Question:**

How do you solve this problem?

---

Okay so I messed it up. The equation really is:

$$ c + d = (c+d) \cdot \text{cos}(\alpha L) + (d-c) \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha L) $$

By the same token then, if we divide by $c+d$, we get the condition that:

$$ \frac{d-c}{c+d} = 1 \; \; \rightarrow \; \; c = 0 $$

This reduces the boundary conditions to:

$$ 0 = d \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha L) $$
$$ d = d \cdot \text{cos}(\alpha L) $$

So it must be that $\alpha_{n} = \frac{2 \pi n}{L}$ for $n=0,1,2,...$

**What do you think?**

Do I need to set c = 0 here? Also, I seems we still have the other $\alpha$ solutions since we still get the $1 = cos() + sin()$ solution...

Edit: Well if $c \neq 0$, then the solution $\alpha_{n} = \frac{2 \pi n}{L}$ still holds, despite $\frac{d-c}{c+d} \neq 1$ because then $sin()$ is identically zero.

Edit: Well the roots of $1 = cos(x) + sin(x)$ is actually $x = 2 \pi n$ according to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=find+roots+of+1+%3D+cos%28x%29+%2B+sin%28x%29 so I guess the solution holds in all cases.

Comment: For most values of $\alpha$ and $L$, the only solution is identically zero.  So: for a fixed value of $L$, you have to find what special values of $\alpha$ will allow a nonzero solution.

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed -- see the plot. We are looking for when the value = 1. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Gonçalo But isn't that the point? Don't we want special values of alpha, because these become the eigenvalues? I suppose if I fix c and d to be dependent on alpha, then they wouldn't be constant anymore...

Comment: @Gonçalo It is? It just seems like I'm getting more complicated trig equations -- after I apply the sum identities that is.

Comment: @Gonçalo Welcome to my life lol It would just be the period of this cosine. $\alpha = \frac{2 \pi n}{L}$, for $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ right?